# Correct usage of malloc/realloc for typedef struct

Tags: c, struct, typedef, realloc

I am having a completely functional program*, but I do have a question about allocating memory, because something is still unclear for me. (*completely functional means, it's having the results I want to have, which can be luck as well).

```
typedef struct Field {
    long index;
    long x;
    long y;
    struct Cell *N;
    struct Cell *S;
    struct Cell *E;
    struct Cell *W;
    int count;
    bool used;
} Field;

typedef struct Construct {
    Field *fs1;
    Field *fs2;
} Construct;

Field *fields;
long countFields = 1;

Construct *constructs;
long countStructs = 1;
```

There are two structs, one called Cell, one called Stone, the Cell has coordinates, an index, a count, a bool and pointers to four other cells.
The Stone just has two pointers to Cells. Both are typedefed for the same name, just appending Td.

So my question is about allocating memory for it.
I am using the following four statements for the first malloc and later on to append more elements.

That is how I have learned it, I guess a can also substitute "CellTd" with "struct Cell" and so on. x is just a factor to talk about my problem.

My current problem is, that I am not sure if this is definitely correct, because I am having different results when increasing x. So when I am working with it, there is sometimes no serious pointer to some elements when the factor x is 1. I am using x=50 then everything is working, but this should not be, how it's working. (Just to say that, for sure, countStones and countCells both in create with the number of elements in the array as well...)

I am doing something wrong with the reallocation?

Comment: Are those four lines of `malloc`/`realloc` calls adjacent as shown, or is there come code in between.  You could indicate that there's code in between with a comment such as `/* ... */` (or `/* … */` if you like).  The notation `ptr = realloc(ptr, newsize);` is inherently dangerous.  If the `realloc()` fails, it returns a null pointer, which means you've leaked the memory because you've overwritten the previous pointer to the memory with a null pointer.  You need to use `void *newptr = realloc(ptr, newsize); if (newptr == NULL) { …handle error… } ptr = newptr;`.

Comment: Your `struct Cell` contains four pointers to `struct Field`, not `struct Cell` as your commentary suggests?  Is this a translation problem?  You `malloc()` using `sizeof(CellTd)`; you `realloc()` using `sizeof(FieldTd)`; one of these is wrong — possibly both.  Similarly for `StoneTd` and `FlagstoneTd`.  It can be sensible to use `cellArr = malloc(x * sizeof(cellArr[0]));` or `cellArr = malloc(x * sizeof(*cellArr));`.  This avoid problems with changing type names.

Comment: The text after "different results when increasing x" is unclear. Please give an example, preferably in the form of "input" and "output". What exactly do you mean by "results"? Is it some value, which is calculated by some unrelated code? Also, phrases like "everything is working" usually require clarifications. See also [mcve].

Comment: Yes it is. Just corrected that as well. Sorry for that, should have read it again after last edit! Now it should be completely ready for asking. Thank you for your idea about handling memory leaks, I have just added that into the topic.

Comment: Is it possible that sizeof(CellTd) is different in different situations, if there is for example NULL for all the for pointers vs. there are for real elements being pointed by them? if yes, then this should be a result for the question.

Comment: how are you using cellArr and stoneArr in the code once it's allocated, I think you have several issues with your code, however since you haven't shared all of it and assumed that it's got do with *alloc and size that you're masking the real issue. please share an [mcve]

Comment: @JonathanLeffler and Ahmed Masud
I have now added the example of my code including the lines where I think something is happening wrong. This is the most minimal example I can extract from my code. Maybe somebody sees the mistake.

Comment: Better style is `pointer = malloc(sizeof *pointer * numelems)`.  Don't repeat the type name. It's easy to mismatch repeated typenames in complicated programs; there is no type checking between the `sizeof` in the `malloc` call and the pointer variable being assigned.  `sizeof *pointer` means "the size of whatever type the pointer points to".

Comment: @Kaz But isn't that exactly what I am doing there in malloc(numelements*sizeof(celltd) ? You are just swaping the two factors.

Comment: `sizeof (CellTd)` and `sizeof *cellArr` have the same value *now*. We could change the program so that they don't, and there won't be any diagnostic.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to allocate an array of things, use [`calloc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/calloc.html). It checks for multiplication overflows and nicely initializes all your values with zeros.

Secondly, make sure you're checking your `calloc` and `realloc` calls for success. If they fail, they'll return null pointers. Then you can use [`perror`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) to determine why they failed, print nice error messages, and quit.

For your logic, here's what a quick gdb session finds with your minimal code (I only changed the type of `i` on line 75 to be `unsigned int`):

At the segfault point:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000401112 in evaluateNeighbourNum (original=0x6034b0)
    at cells.c:153
#1  0x0000000000401350 in evaluateNeighbourNum (original=0x612f20)
    at cells.c:201
#2  0x0000000000401509 in calculate () at cells.c:229
#3  0x00000000004016c8 in main () at cells.c:250

(gdb) p *original
$14 = {
  index = 2, 
  x = 1, 
  y = 0, 
  N = 0x411, 
  S = 0x6e20666f206d754e, 
  E = 0x72756f6268676965, 
  W = 0x2029302c31282073, 
  count = 925966394, 
  used = 48
}
```

As you can see, `N` is getting filled in with garbage (0x411 is not a valid pointer). Take a look at how you're populating your nodes.

Comment: I did just updates my code by handling possible reallocation problems. I do understand your thoughts about calloc as well, but I was not changing it for this topic now. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if I really agree with the `calloc` advice. That imposes extra constraints on the kernel to allocate memory that is zeroed out and is thus more costly. `calloc` is a good choice in some cases, but I disagree that it is always the way to go "if you want to allocate an array of things."

Comment: @cadaniluk that sounds like premature optimization to me. I'd much rather rely on the standard library to check for multiplication overflows than do it myself. If, after profiling, the calloc call turns out to be a significant part of execution time, I'd consider replacing it.

Comment: To me, this is not about optimization. I'm just arguing against `calloc`, not in favor of `malloc`. `malloc` is simply the standard library call to allocate memory to me. `calloc` is for special purposes. Therefore, I wouldn't default to `calloc` just like that. If anything, I would introduce something like `#define ALLOC_MEM` and implement that macro either with `malloc` or `calloc` depending on whether I'm debugging or writing code for release. So much for production code; in this trivial case, `calloc` is OK, but I don't view generally preferring it to `malloc` as good.

Comment: @cadaniluk I wasn't talking about always using `calloc` instead of `malloc`, just when allocating arrays of things, to keep the multiplication out of the function call.